# Загрузка нужного контроллера

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите
что нужно сделать чтоб когда я заново включал приложение которое свернул, загружалось на тот `ViewController` с которым было свёрнуто, ато получаеться , я на 2-м контроллера выхожу, а заходит всё равно через первый.
в приложении всего 4 контроллера: 
`FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController`, `ThirdViewController`, `FourthViewController`.

я так понимаю нужно использовать:
`applicationWillEnterBackground` и `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты в nsuserdefaults сохраняй всегда загруженный (актуальный) контроллер и при запуске приложения просто "бери" последний актуальный и... :)

Push:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:yourActualControllerID forKeyPath:@"ActualView"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Pop:

```
NSInteger tempID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:@"ActualView"];
```

Ну и по коду загружаешь тот view, что тебе нужен :)